# How to stop checkout from TFVC repositories in Azure develops server pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019

**I have found some solution here**: [Checkout part of a branch in Azure DevOps Pipelines (GetSources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442203/checkout-part-of-a-branch-in-azure-devops-pipelines-getsources)

But the concern is I am not using **yml** script to configure the pipeline.
I have configured the pipeline like this:

[image: Getsource in TFS pipeline]

I can view my yml script from here:
[image: View YML]

But not able to edit this script from there

please let me know if anyone has an idea on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the variable `Build.SyncSources = false` in your vNext build definition to disable the get sources step.

Refer to [Disabling Get Sources step in vNext build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tfssetup/disabling-get-sources-step-in-vnext-build) for details. It's also applied to Azure DevOps Server 2019.

[image]

Comment: I have added this variable and its work for me. Thanks @Andy Li-MSFT