# Move/Deploy individual service/project folder to different environments in a Git Mono repo

Tags: git, azure-devops, branching-and-merging, monorepo

Currently, we are going with mono repo approach for our services in azure devops(Git). One issue we are facing is since its a single repository we are unable to move a single service at a time to different environments.

For example, we have
Service 1 (still in development)
Service 2 (still in development)
Service 3 (ready for qa)

Our use case is we need to move only Service 3 related code to qa or higher environments.
Each service has few feature branches which our associated to that service. After the development of the feature we would merge it into a dev branch.

One approach we thought of when moving only a service is cherry-picking commits from initial, but as you see that might be very tedious approach.

So I wanted to know is there a way to move only the service/project folder to different environments. Are there any best practices we need to flow when maintaining a mono repo.

Comment: Hi Sushruth, any update on this, did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have build-in option to get only part of the repository in Azure DevOps pipeline.

As a workaround, you could choose disable the "**Get sources**" step and get only the source you want by manually executing the according git commands in a script.

To disable the default "Get Sources" just specify none in the checkout statement:

```
- checkout: none
```

And then get only part of the repo with **[git sparse-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout)**.

More details you could refer answers in below link: [Checkout part of a branch in Azure DevOps Pipelines (GetSources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442203/checkout-part-of-a-branch-in-azure-devops-pipelines-getsources)

Finally you could also set corresponding CI trigger and  target environment in CD release. Or use [multiple stage pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/multi-stage-pipelines-experience?view=azure-devops).