# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Checkout only folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a YAML pipeline file with the below code:

```
trigger: 
  - none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: SubFolder1
    type: git
    name: MyRepo
```

Here's the repo/folder structure:

```
MyRepo:
- SubFolder1
  -- SubFolder1-2
  -- SubFolder1-2
- SubFolder2
- SubFolder3
File1.txt
file1.json
```

What I need to do is to checkout only the subfolder "Folder1" (along with subfolders under it) from the repo called "MyRepo".  However, the above cold still checkout the entire MyRepo with all the files and other folders underneath it.  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please try to refer this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442203/checkout-part-of-a-branch-in-azure-devops-pipelines-getsources . seems the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think it should work.